# Unable to connect to smb File Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, smb

I am using node.js. The problem is, no matter which module I use, I always end with the following error.

> Error: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xC0000022) : {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.

I have already used smb2 module and some of it's modifications such as `@marsaud/smb2`.

The Server I am trying to connect is a fileserver on the network drive of the college. The fileserver requires a combination of username and password.

The code I am trying to run is:

```js
var SMB2 = require('smb2');
var smb2Client = new SMB2({
 share:'\\\\fileserver2\\Study%20Material\\',
 domain:'JIIT',
 username:'username',
 password:'password'
});
smb2Client.readdir('/', function(err, files){
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log(files);
});
```

I don't know whether it is useful or not, but I have tried to run this code both on Windows and linux.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.

Comment: Is there a question here someplace? Or do you not see the elephant in the room?

Comment: Rights would be restricted only if the username/password is incorrect. This is not the case because I am able to connect to the server via explorer.

Comment: When you connect to the server via explorer the credentials that is being used is the login one (if you did not modify if in the cred manager) and I assume that you logged with a domain credentials. please check again the credentials that you are using and verify that this is not a `WORKGROUP` creds, you can validate it by using network sniff (like Wireshark) and filter it with (`"smb || smb2"`)  and see in the SessionSetup request packet for the `Domain` `User` and the `Password`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I know, this module, smb2, doesn't attempt to login with workgroup credentials.